# How to unit test Angular controller with $scope.$on?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a controller with an event listener in my Angular app, defined as follows.

```
  angular.module('test').controller('TestCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, testService) {

    [...]

    $scope.$on("myEvent", function(args, value) {
      testService.doStuff(value);
    });
  });
```

This works perfectly in the app itself. However, when I try to unit test the functionality of the controller (using *Jasmine* and *Karma*), each test method throws the following error:

```
 TypeError: $scope.$on is not a function in [...]/testController.js
```

I create the controller in my test methods as follows.

```
  it('does stuff', inject(function($rootScope, $controller, testService) {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new;
    $controller('TestCtrl', {
      $scope : scope
    });

    [...]
  }));
```

I can get around the problem by changing my controller to use `rootScope` instead:

```
  $rootScope.$on(...)
```

but then of course the app doesn't work anymore as expected. I can also get rid of the error by introducing the `$on` method in my test code:

```
  var scope = $rootScope.$new;
  scope.$on = function() {};
```

but mocking the listener like this kind of defeats the purpose of testing my real code.

**Why doesn't the test code find the** `$on` **method of the** `scope`**?** (But finds it on `rootScope`, still...)

There must be something fundamental that I'm missing here but I haven't been able to figure it out even after lots of googling and reading the Angular source code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$rootScope.$new` is a function. You need to invoke it (`$rootScope.$new()`):

```js
it('does stuff', inject(function($rootScope, $controller, testService) {
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  $controller('TestCtrl', {
    $scope : scope
  });

  [...]
}));
```

Example plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/t1x62msmOQDkNItGzcp9?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! That was a really embarrassing mistake... (Argh!) I don't know why I had written it like that, but the mistake had infected all of my test classes.